WPF datagrid sizes columns wrong, after resizing window it is correct
After spending quite some time on this issue I decided to post it here.
I have a WPF datagrid. It has a bunch of columns, somehow, when it first loads, the column sizes are wrong. All columns are set to auto, apart from one. As soon as I maximize the app, the columns are good.

The exclamation and error image come from a converter, I first thought this might be causing the problem but if I comment the columns the problem remains, it just moves.

When I set minwidths on the problematic columns, the problem moves to the first column before it. It's like the one column with * is a bit to long, and it cuts one of the other ones to make up for lost width.
Any ideas? Goal is just to have all columns auto and one to * to make it fill the screen.
EDIT:
The XAML:
    <Grid>

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              x:Name="PartsGrid"
              CanUserSortColumns="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
              Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}"
              KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once">

        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:yy/MM/dd HH:mm}}"
                                Header="Date" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                Header="Name"
                                Width="*" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}"
                                Header="Qty" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Thickness}"
                                Header="Thickness" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Material}"
                                Header="Material" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>

Took out a bunch of columns, problem is still there. All columns at default width, one at *. Last column is cropped.


Are you able to share any code? Without that it will be difficult to help.

Sorry, added XAML. But yeah, its basically just a default data grid, with 1 column width *. Am using MahApps + TemplateStudio. In a fresh project with a datagridpage i don't have the problem.

It looks like there is some other styling being applied perhaps by a resource or resource dictionary. That could be affecting the final output. The DataGrid looks and behaves as expected when I run the code you shared
